# I cannot delete all table in sqlplus

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
sql >
DECLARE
     CURSOR ix IS SELECT object_type,
                         object_name
                  FROM all_objects
                  WHERE object_type = 'TABLE' AND owner = 'demo';
BEGIN
     FOR x IN ix LOOP
          EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ( 'DROP ' || 
x.object_type || ' ' || x.object_name || ' CASCADE     CONSTRAINT'
          );
     END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Comment: what's the error you are getting?

Comment: Maybe  due to`owner = 'demo'` , the demo should be in upper case?

Comment: Those numbers are the buffer line numbers as you enter the code into the client; which suggests - since you said 'in shell' - that you're maybe echoing or printing what you've shown and piping it as standard input to SQL\*Plus? Are you sure you really have the final slash, as that should submit the buffer/block? It might be helpful to show the shell code around the call to SQL\*Plus (by [editing your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54674435/edit)).

Comment: Also, It should be `CASCADE CONSTRAINTS`, isn't it?

Comment: So 'from shell' just means from the command line, not from a shell script? Then I misunderstood... the second part still applies though, do you really have the slash (`/`) as the last line as you've shown, and as the first character on that line? Are you hitting return after that character?

Comment: why not `select table_name from all_tables where upper(owner) = 'DEMO'`. And then `'DROP TABLE . . .'` And you need to post the ERROR

Answer (score 0):

Try this please

```
sql >
DECLARE
     CURSOR ix IS SELECT owner , object_type,
                         object_name
                  FROM all_objects
                  WHERE object_type = 'TABLE' AND owner = 'DEMO';
BEGIN
     FOR x IN ix LOOP
          EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ( 'DROP ' || 
x.object_type || ' ' || x.owner||'.'||x.object_name || ' CASCADE   CONSTRAINTS'
          );
     END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try this code,

```
DECLARE
 CURSOR ix IS SELECT owner , object_type,
                     object_name
              FROM all_objects
              WHERE object_type = 'TABLE' And upper(owner) = upper('demo');
BEGIN
 FOR x IN ix LOOP
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ( 'DROP ' || x.object_type || ' ' || 
       x.owner||'.'||x.object_name || ' CASCADE   CONSTRAINTS');
 END LOOP;
END;
```